# Violin plot using specified width instead of density?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple dataframe with 3 columns, `x_group`, `y_value` and `prob` which is a 0-1 number that adds up to 1 over each `x_group`. I am trying to create a simple violin plot where the width of the violin is determined by `prob`.

I tried the following based on some comments I found online:

```
gg_test <- ggplot(data = df, aes(factor(x_group), y_value)) +  
  geom_violin(aes(width=prob), adjust=2)
```

But got the following warning and the graph does not represent what I want.

> The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical
> transformation: width ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the
> correct grouping structure in the data. ℹ Did you forget to specify a
> `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor?

Comment: This warning might be a spurious one which is removed in the dev version of ggplot2.

Comment: Thanks! However, it does seem to signal that the width of the plot is not being determined by "prob", so I don't think it is spurious in this case.